# Table row collapsing?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a problem with collapsing table row data. When I click the button it's toggle all the child row, not exactly row child. Here is snippet:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="">Үйлчилгээний ангилал</th>
          <th class="">Код</th>
          <th class="">Үйлчилсэн тоо</th>
          <th class="">Зарцуулсан мин</th>
          <th class="">Зорилт</th>
          <th class="">Зорилт нөхөх</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody *ngFor="let item of nodes; let i = index">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button
              *ngIf="item.children.length > 0"
              (click)="getChild($event, item.id)"
            >
              <i class="icon-arrow-right5"></i>
            </button>
            {{ item.name }}
          </td>
          <td>{{ item.code }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.count }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.elapsed }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.goal }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.children.length }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr
          *ngFor="let child of item.children"
          [ngClass]="toggleChild ? 'expand' : 'collapse'"
        >
          <td>{{ child.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ child.code }}</td>
          <td>{{ child.elapsed }}</td>
          <td>{{ child.goal }}</td>
          <td>{{ child.goal }}</td>
          <td>{{ child.goal }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

And my typescript file:

```
nodes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Санхүү",
      code: "-",
      count: "986",
      elapsed: "08:29",
      goal: "92%",
      children: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Данс нээх харилцах",
          code: "5545",
          count: "986",
          elapsed: "08:29",
          goal: "92%"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Карт захиалах",
          code: "4587",
          count: "986",
          elapsed: "08:29",
          goal: "82%"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Санхүүгийн бус",
      code: "-",
      count: "986",
      elapsed: "08:29",
      goal: "80%",
      children: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Данс нээх харилцах",
          code: "5545",
          count: "986",
          elapsed: "08:29",
          goal: "92%"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Карт захиалах",
          code: "4587",
          count: "986",
          elapsed: "08:29",
          goal: "82%"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Дундаж",
      code: "-",
      count: "986",
      elapsed: "08:29",
      goal: "80%",
      children: []
    }
  ];
  options = {};

  private getChild(e: any, id: any) {
    this.toggleChild = !this.toggleChild;
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
```

The above code works fine but when I click the button whole child `tr` expanded. What am I doing wrong? What I exactly want is when I click the button it only expands own child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to toggle just one item at a time, just store the selected id in a variable and use it to trigger `ngClass`.

**component.ts** :

```
selectedId : any = '';

private getChild(e: any, id: any) {
    // Check if already expanded
    if(selectedId==id){
        selectedId = '';
    }else{
        selectedId = id;
    }
    ...
}
```

**component.html** :

```
<tr
    *ngFor="let child of item.children"
    [ngClass]="{'expand' : item.id==selectedId, 'collapse' : item.id!=selectedId}"
>
    ...
</tr>
```

And if you want to toggle multiple items at the same time, store the selected id's in an array and use that.

**component.ts** :

```
selectedId : any[] = [];

private getChild(e: any, id: any) {
    // Check if already present in the array i.e. expanded state
    if(selectedId.indexOf(id)>-1){
        // Remove from the array
        selectedId.splice(selectedId.indexOf(id),1);
    }else{
        // Add to the array
        selectedId.push(id);
    }
    ...
}
```

**component.html** :

```
<tr
    *ngFor="let child of item.children"
    [ngClass]=" selectedId.indexOf(item.id)>-1 ? 'expand' : 'collapse'"
>
    ...
</tr>
```

Comment: @batgerel.e I have forgot collapse state for single item case. See updated answer.

Comment: Is it in my answer? If so, I can update it so that others won't stumble on it.

Comment: Yes that `[ngClass]=" selectedId.indexOf(item.id)>-1)` after of `-1 )`